# Attachment Image in popup from feature layer in ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4?

Tags: attachments, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have an attachment in ArcMap attribute table and would like to show the image attachment in the popup when a feature layer element is clicked but the code I tried to show the attachment but this fails

```
popupTemplate.content = [{type: "attachments"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

It fails either because it can't find the popupTemplate in your feature layer. so you have to init the popupTemplate this way :

```
layer.popupTemplate = {content: [{type: "attachments"}]};
```

or because of the typo in your content. You have written **tpye** instead of **type**

Comment: The "type" error was a typo on my side, but I will try to include your snippet and see

Comment: What if there are multiple attachments for the layer but I only wish to pull the attachment for the selected feature item

Comment: this popuptemplate applied to a layer, defines what will be shown when a feature is clicked on.

Comment: Was wondering about a situation where there are multiple attachments to a layer.

Comment: A layer can have multiple features. A feature can have multiple attachments. This popup will display the attachments of the feature you clicked on